# Is the combination switch and outlet circuit in my 1970s home ok?

Tags: electrical, wiring, garage

I’m replacing an existing incandescent light fixture in my garage with two LED fixtures.  The light is on a set of 3-way switches.  I expected to remove the existing fixture and find a hot and neutral.  However, the light is fed by a switched hot and tees into neutral.  It was a bizarre enough setup that I pulled all the faceplates and did some investigating.  If you look at the sketch, L2 is the light fixture that I plan on replacing.

O1 (outlet) and L3 are always hot, and control the garage opener and exterior spotlight, respectively.  S1 has a backstab going to S2 and two wires wrapped around the gold screw.  The part that concerns me is the combination of switched and always-on branches.  Is this type of setup ok?  I imagine it was back in the 70’s when the house was constructed, but now it seems like a ball of yarn.  Thanks

[image]

Comment: What in particular concerns you? I see nothing alarming at first glance. Also, there are no tees in wiring. :P

Comment: Forgot to mention, the fixtures, switches, and receptacles are grounded, I just didn't bother to sketch them in.

Comment: I suspect "tees" == "pigtail"

Comment: And you want more pigtails and fewer backstabs.

Answer (score 2):

Every wire is there for a purpose and there are no extra wires.

It seems like a ball of yarn because *wiring is like that*.   What helps a great deal is color-coding the wires by function.   As an example, I prefer

- white for neutral (well, that's mandatory)
- black for always-hot, circuit 1 (usually the only circuit)
- red for switched-hot (between switch and lamp)
- blue for alt-switched-hot (second lamp)
- yellow for the two 3-way switch *travelers* (the ones on the brass screws) - there is no need to distinguish them from each other

Get a 5-pack of colored tape and apply that by wrapping the appropriate wires.  Yarn no more.